# How can I remove jdownloader?

Tags: removing, jdownloader

How can I remove jdownloader?

I installed it by the following process:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jd-team/jdownloader
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jdownloader
```

Comment: does it work @Nazmul  ?

Answer (score 2):

Open terminal :

```
 sudo apt-get purge jdownloader
```

`purge` used to remove program with its all configuration files .

`remove` used to remove program without its configuration files .

Comment: showing this -->  Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'jdownloader' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 361 not upgraded.

Comment: so its not installed